# Minified CSS not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a page that includes the minified CSS. The page looks fine in all browsers except IE 7,8 and 9

If I add the individual files, it works fine in IE as well but not the .min

This is very strange. Please respond

Comment: This is a very poorly asked question. "My code doesn't work" is extremely hard to debug without seeing the actual code. I would first make sure you're using a CSS minifier, in case the minifier is somehow adding semicolons or something, and from there start with the first element and add piece by piece by hand to see where IE starts to get choked up.

Comment: Assuming your css file is `stylesheet.min.css`, what happens if you rename it to `stylesheet.css`? I seem to recall issues with XP (though some years ago) wherein it sometimes had problems if a file had multiple periods in the filename.

Comment: Microsofts CssMinify class transforms 0.5px to .5px, which doesn't work in earlier IE versions. Half a pixel came out of a less expression. The solution was to change the less expression to round to a whole pixel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common error with minified CSS is not closing off script, this will work fine when you have un minified code because most browsers will pick up the line return.

## Example

**Before**

```
.myclass {
    padding: 1px 2px 4px 5px;
    width:500px
    height:350px;
}
```

**After**

```
.myclass {padding: 1px 2px 4px 5px;width:500pxheight:350px;}
```

Notice the width and height styles are not separated by the semicolon so the browser cant understand what to do with them.

Check that you have closed every class with the appropriate curly brackets  `}` and ended every style with the semicolon `;`

There are many other things that can go wrong including the way you are minimising the CSS. Code examples, explanations about what is actually breaking (is some of the CSS working or none of it working) and more information about the how you are minimizing the CSS will help.

Comment: I think this was the issue...... I have to now manually debug all these files and check if nothing like tht happened. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

You could always use something like this in your index.php,then create IE.css in your site root, then put non minified code into there just for IE.

```
<!-- Code Only For IE -->
<!--[if IE]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./IE.css" />
    <![endif]-->
```

(by the way you can put the css file where you like as long as you update the path in the above script, this is just an example.)

Comment: likewise: <![if !IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./NON_IE_MIN_VERSION.css" />
<![endif]>